# change file names using bash

Tags: bash

Data structure is like following, and I would like to change "lane-7" to "lane-5". 
I am thinking of a command like this, but it does not work.

```
    find PATH -name "lane-7*" | xargs -i echo mv {} `echo {}|sed 's/lane-7/lane-5/'` | sh
```

Anyidea? Thanks

```
PATH/28/lane-7-22.fq
PATH/28/lane-7-21.fq
PATH/28/lane-7-18.fq
PATH/28/lane-7-24.fq
PATH/28/lane-7-23.fq
PATH/28/lane-7-19.fq
PATH/28/27/lane-7-22.fq
PATH/28/27/lane-7-21.fq
PATH/28/27/lane-7-18.fq
PATH/28/27/lane-7-24.fq
PATH/28/27/lane-7-23.fq
PATH/28/27/lane-7-19.fq
PATH/28/27/26/lane-7-22.fq
PATH/28/27/26/lane-7-21.fq
PATH/28/27/26/lane-7-18.fq
PATH/28/27/26/lane-7-24.fq
PATH/28/27/26/lane-7-23.fq
PATH/28/27/26/lane-7-19.fq
PATH/28/27/26/25/lane-7-22.fq
PATH/28/27/26/25/lane-7-21.fq
PATH/28/27/26/25/lane-7-18.fq
PATH/28/27/26/25/lane-7-24.fq
PATH/28/27/26/25/lane-7-23.fq
PATH/28/27/26/25/lane-7-19.fq
...
```

Comment: Look up the `rename` or `prename` commands (not the `rename()` function).  If it exists on your system, use it.  If not, find it; it will be simpler.  (The problem is that the backquoted command is executed before `find` is even started!)

Comment: How does it fail? If you remove the trailing `|sh`, you should see if the command looks right, or what's wrong with it.

Comment: Here are already some good answers. Just some tips. You can't pipe shell commnds to sh. You may write them to the temporary file and execute that for instance. When working with find and xargs, use find -print0 and xargs -0. Then it works also with filenames that consist spaces. You could mess up a lot otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

You could do this with a `while` loop and a bash string substitution:

```
find PATH -name "lane-7*" | while read -r file ; do
  echo mv $file ${file/lane-7/lane-8}
done
```

Remove the `echo` if that appears good.

Answer (score 2):

Use [rename](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rename), it was made for this:

```
find PATH -name "lane-7*" | xargs rename "lane-7" "lane-5"
```

You might have the perl version of [rename](http://man.he.net/man1/rename) instead (Debian installs it by default). In that case, just use a perl expression instead:

```
find PATH -name "lane-7*" | xargs rename "s/^lane-7/lane-5/"
```